# How can I get String value with out double quotation from info.plist in Xcode

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm currently working on iOS project with Xcode. For security purpose, I wrote .xccconfile and remove it from version control. I don't need to commit some api codes in this way. .xccconfig file is like

```
API_KEY = "abcdefg"
```

Then, I set the key in info.plist like this

[image: info.plist]

The problem is when I get the value from info.plist, the value is returned with double quotations.

```
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: "API_KEY") as! String
=> "abcdefg"
```

I'd like to get the value abcdefg, which not with double quotations.

I workaround by removing " by

```
if let str = self.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: key) as? String {
    return str.replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "")
}
```

which I don't want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remove the quotation marks in your config file

`API_KEY = abcdefg`

Comment: Not working *how*? Does it fail to compile? Does it crash at runtime? Does it still have the quotation marks?

Comment: thanks for your reply. I tried just removing quotation from the config files, then now works. It came with double quotation when I tried same way yesterday. thanks anyway